# Why does Number('') returns 0 whereas parseInt('') returns NaN

Tags: javascript

I have gone through similar questions and answers on StackOverflow and found this:

```
parseInt("123hui")
returns 123

Number("123hui")
returns NaN
```

As, `parseInt()` parses up to the first non-digit and returns whatever it had parsed and `Number()` tries to convert the entire string into a number, why unlikely behaviour in case of `parseInt('')` and `Number('')`.

I feel ideally `parseInt` should return `NaN`just like it does with `Number("123hui")`

Now my next question:

As `0 == ''` returns `true` I believe it interprets like `0 == Number('')` which is true. So does the compiler really treat it like `0 == Number('')` and not like `0 == parseInt('')` or am I missing some points?

Comment: Well, that's just how it was designed to work. Or maybe evolved to work that way. Either way, too late to change it. And there are good use-cases for both methods. You just need to pick the one that is appropriate.

Comment: Also note that `Number` also supports floating-point numbers, not just integers.

Comment: Ideally or not, that's not how it works. You might enjoy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqhZZNUyVFM though

Comment: @JonathanLonowski has already given the perfect explanation. Though you can refer to this standard http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7

Comment: It's unclear to me what kind of answer you expect. Do you want someone to cite the spec for you or are you interested in the reasons for this design decision? If the latter, that's not a good question to be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Regarding the last part, you can easily answer that with running `0 == '0foo'`.  If it's `true`, `parseInt` must be used. If it's `false`, something else happened.

Comment: @Rahul Looking in to java source code can give you answer..

Comment: @aProgrammer the question is about javascript -.-

Comment: @TJ, Oh my mistake.. and I was thinking How can someone is instantiating an abstract class...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is due in part to `Number()` making use of additional logic for type coercion. Included in [the rules it follows](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber-applied-to-the-string-type) for that is:

> - A *StringNumericLiteral* that is empty or contains only white space is converted to **+0**.

Whereas [`parseInt()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-parseint-string-radix) is defined to simply find and evaluate numeric characters in the input, based on the given or detected `radix`. And, it was defined to expect at least one valid character.

> 13) If *S* contains a code unit that is not a radix-*R* digit, let *Z* be the substring of *S* consisting of all code units before the first such code unit; otherwise, let *Z* be *S*.
>
> 14) If *Z* is empty, return **NaN**.

Note: '*S*' is the input string after any leading whitespace is removed.

---

> As `0==''` returns `true` I believe it interprets like `0==Number('')` [...]

The rules that `==` uses are defined as [Abstract Equality](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison).

And, you're right about the coercion/conversion that's used. The relevant step is #6:

> If Type(*x*) is Number and Type(*y*) is String,
>   return the result of the comparison *x* == ToNumber(*y*).

Comment: For your typical equality comparison (when you don't try to convert types at the same time), it is usually better to do `===` instead of `==` and avoid the type coercion confusion.

Comment: @Thilo: Well, when you don't convert types because both are the same (as they should be), there is no confusion and you can just use `==` as well.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about `0==''`returning true :

Below is the comparison of a number and string:

**The Equals Operator (==)**

```
Type (x) Type(y)              Result
-------------------------------------------
x and y are the same type      Strict Equality (===) Algorithm
Number  String                 x == toNumber(y)
```

---

and toNumber does the following to a string argument:

```
toNumber:

Argument type    Result
------------------------
String          In effect evaluates Number(string)
                 “abc” -> NaN
                 “123” -> 123
```

`Number('')` returns `0`. So that leaves you with `0==0` which is evaluated using  Strict Equality (`===`) Algorithm

**The Strict Equals Operator (===)**

```
Type            values                        Result
----------------------------------------------------------
Number       x same value as y                true
             (but not NaN)
```

You can find the complete list @ [javascriptweblog.wordpress.com - truth-equality-and-javascript](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/).

Answer (score -1):

`parseInt("")` is `NaN` because the standard says so even if `+""` is `0` instead (also simply because the standard says so, implying for example that `"" == 0`).

Don't look for logic in this because there's no deep profound logic, just **history**.

You are in my opinion making a BIG mistake... the sooner you correct it the better will be for your programming life with Javascript. The mistake is that you are assuming that every choice made in programming languages and every technical detail about them is logical. This is simply not true.

Especially for Javascript.

Please remeber that Javascript was "designed" in a rush and, just because of fate, it became extremely popular overnight. This forced the community to standardize it before any serious thought to the details and therefore it was basically "frozen" in its current sad state before any serious testing on the field.

There are parts that are so bad they aren't even funny (e.g. `with` statement or the `==` equality operator that is so broken that serious js IDEs warn about **any** use of it: you get things like `A==B`, `B==C` and `A!=C` even using just normal values and **without any "special" value** like `null`, `undefined`, `NaN` or empty strings `""` and not because of precision problems).

Nonsense special cases are everywhere in Javascript and trying to put them in a logical frame is, unfortunately, a wasted effort. Just learn its oddities by reading a lot and enjoy the fantastic runtime environment it provides (this is where Javascript really shines... browsers and their JIT are a truly impressive piece of technology: you can write a few lines and get real useful software running on a gajillion of different computing devices).

The official standard where all oddities are enumerated is quite hard to read because aims to be very accurate, and unfortunately the rules it has to specify are really complex.

Moreover as the language gains more features the rules will get even more and more complex: for example what is for ES5 just another weird "special" case (e.g. `ToPrimitive` operation behavior for `Date` objects) becomes a "normal" case in ES6 (where `ToPrimitive` can be customized).

Not sure if this "normalization" is something to be happy about... the real problem is the frozen starting point and there are no easy solutions now (if you don't want to throw away all existing javascript code, that is).

The normal path for a language is starting clean and nice and symmetric and small. Then when facing real world problems the language gains (is infected by) some ugly parts (because the world is ugly and asymmetrical).

Javascript is like that. Except that it didn't start nice and clean and moreover there was no time to polish it before throwing it in the game.

Comment: The example with `==` is terrible: `==` is not transitive in a lot of languages (even in compiled).

Comment: This is a very opinionated and subjective response, it's really just a long comment. I think you have missed the whole point of javascript as a simple, easy to use scripting language in which features like the `==` operator make sense (e.g. so `'1' == 1`).

Comment: @RobG: `==` rules do not make Javascript easy to use, actually it's the opposite. You end up with programs that sometime work and sometime don't for apparently no reason. By the way `1` is also equal to `[1]` and to `"1 "` (blank at the end). But `[1]` is not equal to `"1 "`. The rules are not simple at all, but quite convoluted and strange (check the ecmascript formal standard for some fun)... they just happen to be the formalization of the initial hack. Impressive to be an hack, but still just a non well reasoned hack.

Comment: While I could agree on some of your points, this is a rant, not an answer.

Comment: @Bergi: I actually like Javascript a lot and I'm sorry this is not evident. I tried rewording the answer a bit moving the detail about `+""` to the top hoping to make it sound less "ranting". I still think it's a big error to try to frame Javascript in a logic context...